# How do I set the offset of a div from the top of an outer div to be the same as the offset from the side of the outer div using only css?

Tags: html, css

So I made a mockup of what I want to do so it's easier to understand. I have an outer div that takes up 33% of the page and an inner div that has a width of 50% (of the outer div). The outer div has a "text-align: center;" style so the space on each side of the inner div is 25% the width of the outer div. I want to offset the inner div from the top of the page so it is the same distance from the top as from the sides. Most of the responses to similar questions advise using jquery, but I would prefer to use a css-only solution if there is one. How can i do this?

I apologize if this is a basic question. I am inexperienced with frontend and I couldn't find any way of setting CSS attributes equal to the values of other attributes.

Any help would be appreciated!

The CSS:

```
    .side{
        background-color: #ECEFF1;
        height: 100%;
        width: 33%;
        text-align: center;

    }

    .profpic{
        width: 50%;
        border-radius: 50%;
        position: relative;

    }
```

The Html:

```
        <div class="side mdl-shadow--4dp" >
            <image class="profpic mdl-shadow--4dp" src="/profpic.jpg"></image>

        </div>
        <div class="content">

        </div>
```

[image: mockup]

Comment: Share your code with us.

Comment: oops. How did I forget that? Edited it into the original question

Comment: As far as I know you can't do it in CSS only. You need to reevaluate the top offset in JS on resize to do this.

Comment: It is possible to be done with only CSS :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be achieved simply by just putting these two CSS rules: `padding: 25%` and `width: 50%`. That will center the image equally from the left, top, and right. Here is the code I used:

HTML

```
<div id="side">
    <image src="http://placehold.it/120x120&text=image1" id="box">
</div>
```

CSS

```
#side {
    width: 33.33%;
    height: 1000px;
    background-color: #474747;
}

#box {
    width: 50%;
    padding: 25%;
}
```

Then a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/fhw33cts/) if you would like.

---

**EDIT**

To be a bit more question relevant, this is what the OP's CSS would be:

```
.side{
    background-color: #ECEFF1;
    height: 100%;
    width: 33%;
}

.profpic{
    width: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding: 25%;
}
```

Comment: Perfect! I ended up going with margin:25%; but same idea. So much time wasted and such a simple solution....

Comment: @quantumbutterfly, yea, simple and efficient! :)

Answer (score 2):

As of CSS3 You can use the units `vw` and `vh` to achieve this.

`vh` refers to the height of the viewport, `vw` to its width.

Your `div` is taking `33%` of width, while the inner box `50%` of that. Therefore, your margin on the left and right will be approx `25%` of the outer divs width.

So, what you need as a top-margin is `33% * 25% = 8.25%` of the `vw` unit:

```
<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner">
        lorem ipsum
    </div>
</div>

#outer{
  background-color:red;    
  width:33vw;  
  margin:0;
  padding-top:1px;
  height:100vh;
}

#inner{
    background-color:blue;
    width:50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top:8.25vw; // this is 25% of 33% width
    padding-top:1px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xaLc4zd2/

Resize the windows and see, how the inner div retains its relative position.

Comment: Why not just use `padding: 25%`? That will center it equally from the left, right, and top.

Comment: @MichaelJones that's to easy :-) . No, I think you are right.

Comment: @dognose, yea, I thought so! :)

Comment: Michael Jones' answer is more elegant, so I'm accepting his answer, but thanks for teaching me something new!

Answer (score 0):

This should serve as a reference for your need. The key is to apply box-sizing to the 33% container, and apply 25% margin to the element inside the container.

```
<div class="box">
  <div class="innerbox"></div>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <div class="innerbox"></div>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <div class="innerbox"></div>
</div>


.box{
  width: 33%;
  min-height:400px;
  background-color: #777;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.innerbox{
  width:50%;
  margin:25%;
  min-height:200px;
  background-color: #444;
}
```

See this [codepen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EjEJrx)

Comment: This does not solve the margin-top issue without *magic* numbers....which is the point.

Comment: @Paulie_D, this allows him to fix the left/right/top/bottom distance to 25%. And is responsive up to a certain degree. It is responsive from 830px onwards

Comment: @Ji_in_coding, shouldn't it be `padding: 25%`? That is what seems to make it work.